# QT Designer Qmessagebox GUI Hangs in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface, xmpp

GUI blocks and shows error in VS Code
Error: `QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread`.

and this is code !

```
def ok_handler(self):
    try:
        xmpp = Bot(self.uname.text() + '@', self.password.text())
    except InvalidJID:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error !", "Enter User Details")


def threadstart(self):
    Thread(target=self.ok_handler).start()
```

any solution?

Provide solution how to show `QMessageBox` in thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, Gui operations are handled only in the main thread as I know. If you are running a thread, via signal&slot(thread safe approach) you can trigger a slot in the main thread of the application and show the messagebox.

For example, if you are reading a file, gui operations should be done in the main thread. You can click a button which triggers a file reading method in a different thread and opens a message box which says "Wait until load". in the main thread. When file reading ends, file reading thread can trigger a slot in the main thread which closes the messagebox.

As a result; all gui operations should be done in the main thread but in order not to block the gui, jobs like file reading and networking should be done in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple comments about your code, linked to the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html).

- Your error message is about creating an object with a parent that lives in another thread. This is forbidden.
  **Quote**: *The child of a QObject must always be created in the thread where the parent was created.*
  The underlying reason why this is forbidden is because when an object is destroyed, it deletes all its children. If that were to happen across several thread, you would likely end up deleting an object in `thread 1` while it is being used in `thread 2`. I hope I do not have to explain why that would be a bad thing.
- Subclasses of `QWidget` can only be created from the main thread and cannot be moved to another thread. This is an additional restriction that "regular" subclasses of `QObject` are not subject too.
  **Quote**: *Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be called from that thread.*
  The reason for that is completely different: Qt works on a variety of OS, some of which allow GUI to live only in the main thread. For that reason, moving subclasses of `QWidget` to worker threads was disabled on all OS.

The solution for you is actually simple:

0. It is optional (I think/hope) but I strongly recommend you create a worker object to handle the work that happens in the thread.
1. Create a slot in your main class in charge of showing the `QMessageBox`.
2. Define a signal (e.g. `errorOccured(QString)`) in your worker class; replace `QMessageBox.about(...)` with it.
3. Connect the signal to the slot, with a `Qt.QueuedConnection` (this part is important) before the thread is started.